# TeXstudio: bibliography "I found no style file"

Tags: bibliographies, texstudio

I am using TeXstudio and since today I experience the following issue concerning bibliography:

```
Prozess gestartet: bibtex.exe "dokument"

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.6350 64-bit)
The top-level auxiliary file: dokument.aux
I couldn't open style file bibstyle.bst
---line 224 of file dokument.aux
 : \bibstyle{bibstyle
 :                   }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
I found no style file---while reading file dokument.aux
(There were 2 error messages)

Prozess endete mit Fehler(n)
```

I am using the following commands:

```
\bibliographystyle{bibstyle}
\bibliography{literatur}
```

I didn't make any relevant changes the last days concerning the bibliography, at least not consciously. I just moved the `*.tex` source files from a network drive to local.

Anyone can help me? If necessary I can provide more information.

Comment: Do you have a `bibstyle.bst` file somewhere?

Comment: See my own "solution" below... Thanks for your idea - I don't know why I didn't notice it before. Sorry.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP noticed and corrected the error, see OPs comment and answer.

Answer (score 2):

Ok guys, forget my stupid question...

When moving from the network drive to a local directory, the `bibstyle.bst` file disappeared - don't ask me why. I now recovered it and everything is working fine again!